# Issues updating values in a database table when a parameter contains % in the parameter name

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a php website that contains a page where you can update values of various parameters contained within a database table.
Recently a system admin added some new parameters that contain the % percentage sign at the start of the parameter name and my update function using $_REQUEST superglobal only updates the original parameters that contain alpha characters and new parameters do not update at all.

I need to know how to make a change to my code to support updating of all parameters in the table, no matter the name.

An example of parameters are as follows

Comment: You're having this problem because your code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.  Luckily, the PHP documentation discusses this in detail: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose in brackets:

```
$paramname = str_replace('%', '[%]', $paramname);
```

Or use escape:

```
$paramname = str_replace('%', '\%', $paramname);
$query = "UPDATE Parameters SET Value = '$value' WHERE ParamName = '$paramname' ESCAPE '\'";
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to escape the data before store it in MySQL, you can try with:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: `sqlsrv` not `MySQL`.